# Ubuntu atom unable to get local issuer certificate error

Tags: atom-editor

**Hey, i need help with unable to get local issuer certificate error.**

So bassicaly im very new to ubuntu and I want to use Atom code editor, but i this certificate problem keeps me away from downloading c++ packages (themes included). I've been trying to find a fix on the internet but nothing really works (idk if I'm doing it wrong or something).

Does anyone know a fix or have encountered this problem before? Thanks.

I was trying to download a packadge on atom in ubuntu and this "unable to get local issuer certificate" keeps me from doing that.

Comment: Atom-Editor was replaced by Pulsar-Edit.